# Apache Cordova Media Plugin shows error code 0

Tags: cordova

I am trying to build mp3 player with Apache Cordova. I found that Cordova media plugin provides media play functionality.

Here's the code. I added media and device plugin but it shows error with code 0.

```
function playMP3() {
    var mp3URL = getMediaURL("sounds/button-1.mp3");
    var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, mediaError);
    media.setVolume(1.0);
    media.play();    
}

function playMp3Mild() {
    var mp3URL = getMediaURL("sounds/button-1.mp3");
    var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, mediaError);
    media.setVolume(0.1);
    media.play();
}

function playRemoteFile() {
    var media = new Media("http://SERVER_IP:PORT/media/test.mp3");
    media.setVolume(0.1);
    media.play();
}

function getMediaURL(s) {
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") 
    {
        console.log
        return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
    }
    return s;
}

function mediaError(e) {
    alert('Media Error');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Comment: I noticed that there're error codes in Media plugin.
But there's no error code for 0

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Not yet.
No solutions so I am using HTML5 audio tag instead of media plugin at the moment